# Trigger with 2 tables after update

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'usage' with the following structure:

```
Job | Start Time | End Time | Session
```

And I have another table 'sessions' with the following structure to keep track of sessions:

```
Session Label | Start Time | End Time
```

I want to have a trigger such that when there is an entry in the first table, the trigger will check the start time and end time of other table. If there is a label already that exists, the session column of the first table needs to be updated with the session label, otherwise a new entry should be added to the second table and the corresponding label should be entered into the session column of second table. I have never worked with SQL Triggers before and have no idea how to achieve this.

I tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test AFTER INSERT ON `usage`
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (SELECT RIGHT(`usage`.starttime,5) != SELECT RIGHT(`sessions`.starttime,5))
BEGIN
    SET `usage`.sessionlabel = `A`
END;
```

Logic:

```
for(newrecordinusagetable)
{
//check if same starttime exists in any record of session table
if(true)
{
//do nothing
}
else
{
//add the new starttime to the session table
}
```

PS : Do not bother about the endtime or label.

Comment: Don't do this using a trigger.  Do it using a `JOIN` when you read the data -- unless you have a really good reason for doing real-time.

Comment: i have updated the question can u please help me achieve this using trigger or if join is better how and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt based on the limited info provided:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER usage_session_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON `usage`
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        -- Count sessions with same start time
        DECLARE session_count INT;
        SET session_count = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                             FROM sessions
                             WHERE RIGHT(starttime, 5) = RIGHT(NEW.starttime, 5));

        -- If none found, insert one.
        IF (session_count = 0) THEN
            INSERT INTO sessions (sessionlabel, starttime, endtime)
            VALUES (NEW.`session`, NEW.starttime, NEW.endtime);
        END IF;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Notes**

1. Am assuming you had good reason to compare the last 5 characters of the times in the example so have repeated it here. (Couldn't guess why 5 though!)
2. May also need to consider whether similar triggers are needed for updates (+ possibly deletes?)
3. I'm not commenting on whether what you're asking to do is the correct approach - just attempting to answer the question.

Comment: The above answer is nearly correct but say there is a record with start time : "10:00" already in the session table and another insert into the 'usage' table with start time : "10:00", I don't want it to make a trigger and leave it as such but if there is no match then insert

Comment: Do you mean you want to do the look-up just based on start times and update the end time in addition to the session label?

Comment: ...Have updated my answer assuming that is the case.

Comment: Let me explain it little more better, i don't need to care about endtime. There shouldn't be duplicate entries with same starttime. To avoid this i need to check last 5 digits of start time if the same time exists in the table then do not insert again and skip to next record else make a new entry in the table.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "skip to next record" - the trigger is operating in the context of a *single record* being inserted into the usage table. Do you want an UPDATE to happen at all in the event of the starttime being found in the session table? If so, do you want *only* the sessionlabel to be updated or do you want the endtime to be updated as well?

Comment: I have put a snippet into the question again check in 2 mins

Comment: OK - so no update to the session record then - you might like to update your question text above to make this clear. Have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

From better solution perspective it would be better to implement this in application logic when data is inserted into usage table, instead of creating trigger to achieve this. To demonstrate your sceanrio, I have used a stored procedure to insert into usage table. You can modify it accordingly.

```
-- create usage table
create table `usage` ( job varchar(100), 
               start_time date, 
               end_time date, 
               `session` varchar(100) 
             );

-- create `sessions` table
create table `sessions` ( session_label varchar(100) , 
              start_time date, 
              end_time date );

-- create procedure prc_insert_into_usage
delimiter $$

Create Procedure prc_insert_into_usage
(
    IN p_job varchar(100), 
    IN p_start_time date, 
    IN p_end_time date
)
Begin
  Declare v_session varchar(100);

  -- check if record is there in the session table
  -- it is assumed session table will have only one record for composite key (start_time, end_time)
  Select session_label into v_session 
  from `sessions` 
  where start_time = p_start_time and end_time = p_end_time;

  IF (v_session IS NULL ) THEN

    -- if session_label is generated using auto increment key in sessions table then 
    -- last_insert_id() can be used to fetch that value after insert into sessions table 
    -- which can be used while inserting into usage table 
    -- example below
    -- Insert into `sessions` (start_time,end_time) values (p_start_time,p_end_time);
    -- set @v_session = last_insert_id();
    -- Insert into `usage` values (p_job,p_start_time,p_end_time,@v_session);

    -- dummy logic to create the session_label
    -- dummy logic is used you can replace it with whatever logic you need
    set @v_session = concat('sess_',left(uuid(),8));

    -- insert record in both table (first in session table and then in usage table)
    Insert into `sessions` values (@v_session,p_start_time,p_end_time);
    Insert into `usage` values (p_job,p_start_time,p_end_time,@v_session);

  else 
    -- record already present in sessions table for this session label
    -- so insert record only in usage table
    Insert into `usage` values (p_job,p_start_time,p_end_time,@v_session);

  End If;

End;

$$

-- call this procedure to insert data into usage table
-- sample execution below when both tables have no rows
-- below call will insert 1 rows in both table having same session label
mysql> call prc_insert_into_usage('job_a','2015-01-01','2015-01-02');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from `usage`;
+-------+------------+------------+---------------+
| job   | start_time | end_time   | session       |
+-------+------------+------------+---------------+
| job_a | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-02 | sess_abc376bf |
+-------+------------+------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from `sessions`;
+---------------+------------+------------+
| session_label | start_time | end_time   |
+---------------+------------+------------+
| sess_abc376bf | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-02 |
+---------------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

-- below call will insert only in usage table as row already present in sessions table
mysql> call prc_insert_into_usage('job_b','2015-01-01','2015-01-02');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from `usage`;
+-------+------------+------------+---------------+
| job   | start_time | end_time   | session       |
+-------+------------+------------+---------------+
| job_a | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-02 | sess_abc376bf |
| job_b | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-02 | sess_abc376bf |
+-------+------------+------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from `sessions`;
+---------------+------------+------------+
| session_label | start_time | end_time   |
+---------------+------------+------------+
| sess_abc376bf | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-02 |
+---------------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- below call will again insert rows in both table
mysql> call prc_insert_into_usage('job_c','2015-01-02','2015-01-04');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from `usage`;
+-------+------------+------------+---------------+
| job   | start_time | end_time   | session       |
+-------+------------+------------+---------------+
| job_a | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-02 | sess_abc376bf |
| job_b | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-02 | sess_abc376bf |
| job_c | 2015-01-02 | 2015-01-04 | sess_dcfa6853 |
+-------+------------+------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from `sessions`;
+---------------+------------+------------+
| session_label | start_time | end_time   |
+---------------+------------+------------+
| sess_abc376bf | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-02 |
| sess_dcfa6853 | 2015-01-02 | 2015-01-04 |
+---------------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```